# Perl Dancer or Node.js for small application

Tags: node.js, perl, design-patterns, web, dancer

I am using Perl Dancer to develop an application handling 
minimal routes and requests.

What is the difference between Perl Dancer (micro web framework) and 
Node.js ? which ll be better Node.js or Perl Dancer?

Comment: Well, with one you write Perl and with the other you write Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for the tool that makes you more productive, both tools may be similar for your purposes. I'll recommend you use Dancer if you have Perl knowledge. Or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) for Python, [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/) for Ruby, ...

for Perl, Dancer is a great web framework. See also: [Mojolicious::Lite](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojolicious::Lite) and [Kelp](https://metacpan.org/pod/Kelp).